# Streaming my camera's output to another PC in the same network Python

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, video-streaming

I'm looking for a method to stream my PC's camera to another PC in the same network using Python.

I thought about using OpenCV module to capture my camera's output and then to serialize the 3 dimensional array to bytes and sending it using sockets but the thing is that this is a lot of bytes to send.
For example if I reduce the camera's output to 480* 640 every frame is 480*640*3 bytes( The 3 is for RGB) .

I can optimize this if I use a gray scale video.

Any other ideas that are not sockets ?

Comment: Interframe compression?

Comment: You could use gstreamer with opencv. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46636126/2286337) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045135/2286337).